# How to keep strikethrough when adding a new one in a textview? The strikethrough jumps to the newest highlighted word

Tags: ios, swift, textview, strikethrough

I have a textview and it's set as an attributed text. When I use this code and click my button to strikethrough it will strikethrough the highlighted section perfectly. But when I highlight another section and click strikethrough it clears the first one and the new highlighted section I strikethrough gets the line.

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textView.text)
attributeString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: textView.selectedRange)

textView.attributedText = attributeString
textView.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 16.0)
```

How can I keep it for all sections? Where it won't clear out unless I clear it myself? I guess I didn't realize how would I clear it also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new attributed string with no attributes, then you add the one strikethrough.

Instead, update the existing attributed string.

```
let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly I just had to switch 

NSMutableAttributedString(string:

to

NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:

thank you so much been working on this for 3 days and it drove me nuts!

Comment: You had to change that line as I show in my answer. There are two changes on that line, not one.

Comment: Gotcha Thanks I see it now attributed text also not text. thanks a million!